# Aspect not being invoked on SpringBoot API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, aspect

I created an annotation to execute something before and after the rest call(Around).

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

and an aspect to cut the execution and do my custom actions

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class Aspect {

    @Around("@annotation(myAnotation)")
    public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MyAnnotation annotation) throws Throwable {
    //DoSomething
    Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
    //DoSomthing
        return result;
    }
```

So, in my controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class SomeController {
  @MyAnnotation()
  public Response someaction(){
    ...
   }
}
```

My problem is that when i test this and import

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
  AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.class,
```

The process method is called and my custom action is invoked and executed but when i test manually in mi Spring API, the process method is never invoked and execute only the action controller

Comment: Use full qualified class name instead of just `myAnnotation`

Comment: It should be sth like     @Around("@annotation(mypackage.MyAnnotation)")

Comment: @gtiwari333 I repeat that when i test it and put a breakpoint in the process method the methos is invoked

Comment: show the full code of the test and post which version of Spring Boot you are using? is that unit test or integration test? Try annotating your test class with @SpringBootTest

Comment: @gtiwari333, the syntax `@annotation(myAnotation)` is correct in this case, because the OP binds the annotation to the advice method parameter `MyAnnotation annotation`, so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @AlexRoitman, please publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, so the community here can reproduce your problem. With the information given, there are too many possible root causes. I want to analyse your problem, not speculate. At the moment I cannot even understand your problem description. E.g., when does it work? What "manual test" are you performing when it does not work?